# Can long cycle rides cause damage to people fitted with a bladder sphincter

Tags: health

Can any body tell me if they have experienced any problems or pain. I have a bladder sphincter fitted and am concerned about doing a long bike ride. My question is I am currently training for a 10 day cycle ride with an average distance of 70 miles per day, total 700 miles in July. I have started to get some niggles (cramp) with over filled bladder. The valve goes off frequently causing leakages.

Love to hear from cyclist with similar experience.

Comment: I know an avid cyclist who had severe prostate problems and had to cut way back on cycling, then quit entirely.  Don't know if he used any sort of Foley or such.  At one point he was riding on a sling-style seat, but I never asked him if it helped much.

Comment: I know 2 cancer survivors who successfully switched to recumbents.

Comment: Probably should talk to a doctor.